# Export new orders to individual CSV files

Tags: orders, csv, export

Could someone tell me how to export each new order from Magento to individual CSV files and save them on the server?

Answer (score 1):

@ Jmarles, you can follow the bellow link , its crate a .txt file when new order create.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514453/export-order-info-to-txt-file-once-order-is-placed

or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968336/magento-automatically-create-csv-file-for-each-order-placed